# Points to path algorithm - is it possible to keep the attributes in the new file (lines) from the source file (points)

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, points-to-line

In my dataset of points, I need first to group points by ID, sort them by time and for each group to draw a line by time order. And for that processing algorithm `points to path` works perfectly. But my problem is that I lose all the attributes of points after running the algorithm. It would mean to me that at least ID of each group of points became ID for the corresponding line. I have some attributes that are for each group the same and it is really important not to lose them after running the algorithm.

In order to better understand my problem, my dataset looks like as:

```
ID      TIME        kv           X       Y
1        00:00      a2         x coord   y coord
1        00:05      a2         x coord   y coord
1        01:00      a2         x coord   y coord
1        03:00      a2         x coord   y coord
2        00:00      a6         x coord   y coord
2        17:00      a6         x coord   y coord
3        05:00      ab         x coord   y coord
```

And my output should be the set of lines with the kv column, so for each user, I should have a line between points by time order:

```
ID    kv    GEOMETRY
1     a2         geom
2     a6         geom
3     ab         geom
```

And the real output in after finishing algortithm looks as this:

```
ID                  GEOMeTRY        
new-random-id1       line-geom         
new-random-id2       line-geom
new-random-id3       line-geom
```

Are there any alternative approaches?

Comment: This is a basic exercise in normalization. If it is not possible to merge your unvarying properties, then you need to choose one, then join back to the target.

Comment: Would using python pandas be an option?

Comment: Yeah, why not :)

Comment: And btw Vince, there is no normalization, this column weight and its numbers is just example here. I made it up.

Comment: You made up an inaccurate example, and you think that will help?

Comment: I just thought that people won't go into the depper meaning of columns. I will change it now.

Comment: I changed it now. :)

Comment: It's still an exercise in normal form.  You don't need to go to third-order to identify that ID and kv correlate, and therefore one can be used as a lookup for the other.

Comment: Pandas seems like extreme overkill here -- why not just use "join attributes by field value" and copy the desired columns from your source layer?

Comment: Because, qgis gives to features entirely new ID, I don't have a common feature.

Comment: Which qgis version are you using? Current releases keep the grouping field in the output. Are you using 2.18?

Comment: No, QGIS 3.4 and it doesn't keep for sure. Or just mine doesn't keep. I will upgrade it. Thanks for the tip. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pandas. You will have to adjust the code to match your fieldnames, time format etc. To create lines you cant have only one entry, like your ID 3. If you do you will need to adjust the code.

Data in csv file:

```
ID,TIME,kv,X,Y
1,00:00,a2,587667.4987,6268456.463
1,01:00,a2,587667.4987,6270394.893
1,00:05,a2,590173.2747,6270253.057
1,03:00,a2,592064.4264,6271151.354
2,17:00,a6,590456.9474,6255454.795
2,00:00,a6,591166.1293,6254367.382
3,05:00,ab,589653.2079,6256636.765
3,02:00,ab,589600,6256600
```

Example code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString

data = r'C:\Test\Timestamps2.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(data)

#Convert string/text/object time to datetime time
df['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME']).dt.time
df.sort_values(by='TIME', inplace=True)

#Create XY column
df['XY'] = list(zip(df['X'],df['Y']))

#Group by ID. Any aggfunc is possible, python build-in or own. Also possible to have multiple funcs per field.
aggfuncs = {'TIME':'first', 'kv':'first', 'XY':list}
df2 = df.groupby('ID').agg(aggfuncs)

#Create geodataframe
geometry = [LineString([Point(p) for p in row]) for row in df2['XY']]
crs = {'init':'epsg:3006'}
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df2, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)

#Export to file
gdf.reset_index(inplace=True) #To keep ID column
del gdf['XY']
del gdf['TIME']
gdf.to_file(r'C:\Test\Timestamp2shape.shp', driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

[image]