# Representing day/night routes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, points-to-line

I'm working with QGIS 3.22.11-Białowieża and I've got a point layer that represents the migration route of a bird species. Each point has the following attributes:

- `trip` that identifies a single trip (all points of a certain individual and route -northwards or southwards- have the same value for that field)
- `time_stamp` that holds date for that position
- `day_night` that indicates whether the position was obtained during day or night time.

Using the `Point to Path` algorithm I can easily represent each migration route, using the `trip` attribute as grouping expression and the `time_stamp` as the order expression. But I need to represent in different colours the night and day stretches of each route, as the points in the image below, and the `point-to-path` algorithm doesn't seem to be able to hold that variable (only the trip id and the begin and end date).

[image]

Data for this example can be downloaded [here](https://disk.yandex.com/d/hKIvat_JoQTLyA).

I've found [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321066/points-to-path-algorithm-is-it-possible-to-keep-the-attributes-in-the-new-file) with some hints, but my knowledge of Python is still too limited. Is there a way or workaround to do that representation?

Comment: You state that your data contains the field "..time_stamp that holds date and time for that position..."  However, when I download your data I do not see that field.  Instead I see the field **date_time**, which only contains the date - *not time*.  It seems to me that having the time is required because the bird travels sequentially along many points during each day.  Did I miss something?

Comment: You're right @StuSmith. Edited

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Divide the line in segments and assign each segment the daynight value of the closest point:

1. Explode lines
2. Add an attribute with field calculator: `overlay_touches ('foo_points', daynight)[0]`
3. Assign different colors based on this attribute with Categorized layer styling.

*Even easier, I introduced the expression directly in the Categorized styling dialog, thus doing step 2 and 3 in a single step:*

[image]

If you want to filter to catch only points with the same trip id (what seems not necessary, as long as you don't have points belonging to different trips in exactly the same spot, what seems unlikely), it's a bit more complicated. Unfortunately, filtering inside overlay functions in QGIS 3.28 still [does not work as described here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/415248/88814). But you can use this expression instead:

```
array_sort (
    array_foreach (
        overlay_touches ('foo_points', $id),
        if (
            attribute (get_feature_by_id ('foo_points',@element), 'trip') = trip,
            attribute (get_feature_by_id ('foo_points', @element), 'daynight'),
            ''
        )
    ),0
)[0]
```

Comment: And what would be the filter so the `overlay_touches` function only affected points with the same `trip` value as the exploded line?

Comment: `overlay_touches` anyhow only finds points that `touch` the line, so I guess you don't have points of different trip in exactly the same spot, do you?

Comment: I honestly don't know. It is just to work on the safe side.

Comment: See updated answer